# Find free username based on schema

Tags: ruby, recursion, ruby-on-rails, regex

Hopefully this is not too complicated. I have this code that will generate a username based on the pre-configured schema the admin types in. The fields they can use are:

```
<first_initial>
<last_initial>
<first_name>
<last_name>
<role>
```

So, if my name were John Doe, and I had the role of "author" in the system, the function would translate these `UsernameSchema` thusly:

```
<first_name>.<last_name>         = john.doe
<first_intitial><last_name>      = jdoe
<first_name>.<last_name>-<role>  = john.doe-author
<last_initial>                   = d
```

Obviously, it needs to check for duplicates. Below is the working code I have (will be called either `after_initialize` or `before_create` (not sure which at this point):

```
  def set_username
    schema = UsernameSchema.where(:active => true).first! || "<first_initial><last_name>"
    fname = self.first_name
    lname = self.last_name
    finit = fname[0]
    linit = lname[0]
    urole = self.role
    # Question 2:
    replacement_dict = {"<first_initial>" => finit, "<last_initial>" => linit, "<first_name>" => fname, "<last_name>" => lname, "<role>" => urole}
    replacement_regex= /(<first_initial>)|(<last_initial>)|(<first_name>)|(<last_name>)|(<role>)/
    proposed_username = schema.gsub(replacement_regex, replacement_dict).downcase
    self.username = find_free_name(proposed_username)
  end

  # Question 3, IDE complains about next line
  def find_free_name(un)
    user = User.find_by_username(un)
    if user
      num = user.scan(/\d+$/).first
      if num
        new_num = num.to_i + 1
        next_user = un.gsub(num, new_num.to_s)
      else
        next_user = un + "1"
      end
      find_free_name(next_user)
    else
      un
    end
  end
```

I guess I have these concerns with my code:

1. Is this a dumb way of doing it?
2. Where my "Question 2" comment is in the above code, that seems redundant... is there a more succinct way?
3. My IDE says I'm doing it wrong (and I don't know what it wants):

> All custom “finds” accessed from more than one place in the code use
>   named_scope instead of a custom method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code here seems a bit over complicated for its intended purpose.

Would there be some issue with just appending a random number or hash to the end of each user name? something like taking all the user provided information and creating a sha-1 hash then just using the first 3 or so characters?

```
data = [fname,lname,fint,lint,urole]
Digest::SHA1.base64digest(data.join('')) 
#=> f1ed8d7c48b27af459240984574c7bcd8b14fe4b
```

This would give you a very unique string to add to each username.

Comment: I never really thought of that. It's not what I'd like to do, but I guess I could do that. I would still need to check for collisions, right? I mean it would be unlikely that I'd have one, but shouldn't I still check?